# ms crm 2011 set fetchxml on subgrid control on Dashboard via ribbon button js

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dashboard

I am trying to pass custom fetchxml to a sub grid on a new dashboard I created.
The problem is the dashboard does not use the name I specified in design mode to uniquely identify the grid.

The code I have that works on sub grids on standard entity forms

```
var subGrid = document.getElementById("mygrid");
    subGrid.control.SetParameter("fetchXml", fetchxml);
    subGrid.control.refresh();
```

I have tried to identify the grid by looking at the html mark up. I am able to get the control from this id which appears to be grid

```
document.getElementById('Component7784664_span').control
```

However, it does not have the 'SetParameter' or 'refresh' method.

Any help appreciated.

thanks

Comment: What event do you use to fire this javascript?

Comment: I have a button in the ribbon which loads the JavaScript resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the page was cached, after clearing the cache and refreshing the page, the grid could be found using the assigned id.